# jpa keep foreign collection

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "THISBEAN")
public class ThisBean {
    ...
@OneToMany(targetEntity = SomeBean.class, mappedBy = "thisBean", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH})
private List<SomeBean> bean;

...
}
```

And when I remove ThisBean, SomeBean should be kept. It works fine, bet when I later want to access SomeBean using `entityManager.find(persistentClass, id);`, it gives me exception `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.xxx.yyy.ThisBean with id someId`
I looked into table `SomeBean`, and the foreign key referencing to ThisBean is there. How do I resolve it so I can access `SomeBean` instance from database later? Here is the code of SomeBean class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOMEBEAN")
public class SomeBean {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "THISBEAN")
private ThisBean thisBean;

...
}
```

Comment: What JPA provider are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The thief killed the batman's parents, yes surely batman has parents' memories but they don't help them come alive**

When you call `em.remove(id);` database row is deleted from database.
When you call `em.find(SomeClass.class, id);` entityManager tries to find a row with matching primary key hence you get the `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`

> How do I resolve it so I can access SomeBean instance from database later? Here is the code of SomeBean

Even though you can get the id of `ThisBean` from `SomeBean` by performing some jpql function or other way, `ThisBean` database table doesn't contain any row with mathing `id` so its not possible to get the entity back.

If you really want to do that, then create a new entity with same `id` then call `em.persist(thisBeanEntity)` which makes it **managed** and then again call `em.find(id)`

**EDIT**

Before you remove **ThisBean** try setting it to `null` from `SomeBean`

```
someBean.setThisBean(null);
```

This way you will break the relationship and foreign key column value will be `null`.

**Remember that maintaining the entity relationship is the responsibility of application (or developer) and not the jpa implementation.**

Even when you are using bidirectional relationship, you need to set both entities from either sides.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I do not need ThisBean entity back. I just cannot access SomeBean anymore since foreign object ThisBean has been removed.

Comment: Yes, it has primary id and foreign(ThisBean) id. And when I try to find SomeBean, it automatically looks up ThisBean by this foreign id and since it cannot find it, it throws exception. So what I wan tis to say this field that it doesn't have to exist.

Comment: as far as I understand, this is not possible, because there will be an exception as both entities are bound by bidirectional relationship. I've updated my answer please check whether it works for you.

Comment: Yes! I set them to null when I remove ThatBean and it fixed the issue. Not sure if it is a good way to manually do it, but at least it works.

Comment: @Heisenberg don't worry about its being a good way or not. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75799/discussion-between-prasad-kharkar-and-heisenberg).